# Multiple keys one value

Tags: python

I'm trying to use dictionary with multiple keys assigned to one value.

For example:

```
my_arg = 'MARY'
my_dict = {('Al','AMY','45'): 'ZONE1', 
           (56,'LO','MARY','ELM'): 'ZONE2',
           (75,'SF','KIM','CORE'): 'ZONE3'}
```

I need to get the value if one passed argument matches one of the keys.

Comment: That's not a dictionary with multiple keys assigned to one value, it's a dictionary with tuple keys. You could expand that to the former if you wanted to, then the lookup would be trivial.

Comment: `{k2: v for k1, v in my_dict.items() for k2 in k1}`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I closed the question because it seems to be a duplicate of an earlier question. If that's incorrect, please [edit] and clarify what makes this different, as well as what research you've already done. For more tips, see [ask].